# Bind results of client side calculations to control (e.g. chart)

Tags: sapui5

If the source for my chart in SAP UI5 is not a model loaded from a server or file, but the result of some calculations (groupings/maths) based on an existing model, how do I correctly bind it to the chart control and use the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first create the outcome of the calculation. Then you transfer it in a new JSON model and use the setData function to pass the results.
Then you bind the control to the new JSON model. I try to make up some dummy code probably located in your controller:

```
var data = modelWithRawData.getData();
calculationOutput = doComplicatedCalculation(data);

var calculationModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(calculationOutput)
myView.setModel(calculationModel, "calculationModel");
```

And in the path of your bindings you now need to reference the modelName. Eg in an xmlView:

```
<Chart data="{calculationModel>/PathToRelevantData}"> 
<!-- more xml -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using the sap.viz library:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />

    <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.ux3,sap.ui.table,sap.m,sap.viz" 
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
    </script>

<script>
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        businessData : [
            {text: "A", value: 100},
            {text: "B", value: 200},
            {text: "C", value: 300}
        ]
    }); 

    //DO SOME ADVANCE CALCULATION WITH THE JSON DATA...
    var data = oModel.getData();
    data.businessData[0].value += 30;
    data.businessData[1].value = data.businessData[1].value * 2;
    data.businessData[2].value = data.businessData[2].value - 100;
    //END OF SOME ADVANCE CALCULATION WITH THE JSON DATA...

    var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
            dimensions : [{axis : 1, name : 'Text', value : "{text}"}],
            measures : [{name : 'Value', value : '{value}'},
        ],
        data : {path : "/businessData"}

    });
    var oBarChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Bar({
        title : {
            visible : true,
            text : 'My bar chart'
        },
        dataset : oDataset
    });

    // attach the model to the chart and display it
    oBarChart.setModel(oModel);

    oBarChart.placeAt("content");
</script>

</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.